# Calling a php function as a parameter inside a function call

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to printing data from a database to the [hcard](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard) format:

```
...
<span class='n'>
<span class="given-name">John</span>
...
</span>
```

Then I created this php function:

```
function print_row ($html_tag, $type, $value) {
    echo '<'.$html_tag.' class="'.$type.'">'.$value.'</'.$html_tag.'>';
}

// Calling function
print_row('span', 'given_name', 'John');

// Output
<span class="given_name">Nathan</span>
```

This worked as I expected until I tried calling my `print_row` function as a parameter of the `print_row` function.

```
print_row('span', 'n', print_row('span', 'given_name', 'Nathan'));

// Output
<span class="given_name">Nathan</span>
<span class="n"></span>

// Wanted Output
<span class="n"><span class="given_name">Nathan</span></span>
```

1. Why is my second 'print_row' function call not inside my first'print_row' function call?
2. Is this even impossible? ([PHP - Can I pass a function name as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261415/php-can-i-pass-a-function-name-as-a-function-argument))

Comment: You should consider a templating system to make this a whole lot easier: http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/19-promising-php-template-engines/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost *always* use `return` instead of `echo` in function calls.

Why? Because `return` returns the data and lets you both store AND echo it. `echo` just renders it to the browser.

An example of a basic `return` and `echo` function is [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). It either does a `echo`, or a `return` if second parameter is TRUE.

---

You should change

```
function print_row ($html_tag, $type, $value) {
    echo '<'.$html_tag.' class="'.$type.'">'.$value.'</'.$html_tag.'>';
}
```

to

```
function print_row ($html_tag, $type, $value) {
    return '<'.$html_tag.' class="'.$type.'">'.$value.'</'.$html_tag.'>';
}
```

and echo the function accordingly on existing places.
That or add a 4th parameter that `return` instead of `echo`:

```
function print_row ($html_tag, $type, $value, $bool = FALSE) {
    $str = '<'.$html_tag.' class="'.$type.'">'.$value.'</'.$html_tag.'>';
    if ($bool)
        return $str;
    else echo $str;
}

print_row('span', 'n', print_row('span', 'given_name', 'Nathan', TRUE));
// Added a ', TRUE' at the second last ')'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to return the value from the function, not `echo` it.